# Backbone: Using views inside _.template

Tags: javascript, templates, backbone.js, view, underscore.js

Im trying to create a dynamic Widget system to create panels inside my page.
Lets took a single example:

```
                Widgets.create({
                    name : 'menu-site',
                    title: 'Menu', 
                    content: 'This is my menu!'
                });
```

It will render this:

```
<section class="widget menu-site">
    <h1>Menu</h1>
    <article>This is my menu!</article>
</section>
```

Its ok right? I have done it thousand times.
However, the problem starts when i try to use a view inside:

```
                var view = new MyCustomView;                  
                Widgets.create({
                    name : 'custom-panel',
                    title: 'Custom Panel', 
                    content: view.render().el
                });
```

I can render the content by calling the outerHTML inside the WidgetView, however, when i do it, the events declared inside MyCustomView does not work!

Someone ever faced this problem?

For those who need more details, this is my WidgetView code:

```
        var Widget = Backbone.Model.extend({
            defaults : function() {
                return {
                    title : '',
                    content : '',
                    closeable : true
                }
            }
        });
        var WidgetList = Backbone.Collection.extend({
            url : '/widgets',
            model : Widget
        });
        Widgets = new WidgetList;


        var WidgetView = Backbone.View.extend({
            tagName : 'section',
            className : function() {
                return ['widget',' ', this.model.get('name')].join('');
            },
    template: _.template($('#widget-template').html()),

            events : {
                "click .close" : "removeWidget"
            },

            initialize : function() {
                this.listenTo(this.model, 'destroy', this.remove);
            },


            removeWidget  : function() {
                this.model.destroy();
            },

            render: function() {
              this.$el.append(this.template(this.model.toJSON()));   
              return this;
            },
        });

        var AppViewport = Backbone.View.extend({
            el : $("#widgets"),

            events : {
            },

            initialize : function() {
                this.listenTo(Widgets, 'add', this.addNewWidgetView);
            },

            addNewWidgetView : function(widget) {
              var view = new WidgetView({model: widget});
              this.$el.append(view.render().el);
            }
        });

        new AppViewport;
```

Or maybe, im thinking about another workaround for this..
But i wasted so much time trying to understand this problem that i just cant see the light!

**UPDATE --------------- 18/01 ---------**

I made some tests, and changed my code:
Instead of using an underscore template, i created a WidgetViewLayout, and did all the template work manually:

```
            var WidgetView = Backbone.View.extend({
                tagName : 'section',
                className : function() {
                    return ['widget',' ', this.model.get('name')].join('');
                },

                events : {
                    "click .close" : "removeWidget"
                },

                initialize : function() {
                    this.listenTo(this.model, 'destroy', this.remove);
                },


                removeWidget  : function() {
                    this.model.destroy();
                    MenuRouterInstance.navigate('');
                },

                render: function() {
                    var layout_view = new WidgetViewLayout({model: this.model.toJSON()});
                    this.$el.append(layout_view.render().el);   
                    return this;
                }
            });

            var WidgetViewLayout = Backbone.View.extend({
                tagName : 'div',

                render : function() {
                    var title = this.model.title,
                        content = this.model.content,
                        closeable = this.model.closeable || false;

                    var anchor = this.setupAnchor(closeable),
                        h1 = this.setupH1(title, anchor),
                        article = this.setupArticle(content);

                    this.$el.append(h1);
                    this.$el.append(article);

                    return this;
                },

                setupH1 : function(title, target) {
                    var element = $('<h1 />');
                    element.text(title);
                    element.append(target);   

                    return element;
                },

                setupAnchor : function(closeable) {
                    var element = '';
                    if(closeable == true) {
                        element = $('<a />'); 
                        element.addClass('close');
                        element.text('(fechar)');
                    }

                    return element;
                },

                setupArticle : function(content) {
                    var element = $('<article />');
                    element.append(content);

                    return element;
                }
            })
```

It seems to work now, but i still have some problems with the views created inside my Widget, like that:

```
                    var view = new MyView;                  
                    Widgets.create({
                        name : 'menu',
                        title: 'My menu', 
                        content: view.render().el
                    });
```

When MyView creates multiple SubViews inside itself, and i call model.destroy to remove one of the Subview's Model, the listened method "this.remove" ends up removing all SubViews, instead of removing only one. In the end, i was forced to do this:

```
                removeit : function(removed_item) {
                    if(removed_item.get('name') == this.model.get('name')) {
                        this.remove();                            
                    }
                },
```

I dont know if its a bad pattern, but it have worked!
I appreciate if someone had a better idea!

][`,s

Answer (score 3):

I think your problem is that you're trying to treat a DOM element object (`el`) as a string. When you do this:

```
content: view.render().el
```

you'll have a live DOM node in `content` and the view's events will be bound to that DOM node. You can use one of the HTML methods (apparently `outerHTML` in your case) to get the node's HTML through your template but [`delegate`](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/) that handles the events is bound to the DOM node, not to the string of HTML that you end up working with.

You could modify your `render` a bit to work with the raw DOM node as-is when necessary, something like this.

```
render: function() {
    var json = this.model.toJSON();
    if(_(json.content).isString()) {
        this.$el.append(this.template(json));
    }
    else {
        var content = json.content;
        delete json.content;
        this.$el.append(this.template(json));
        this.$('article').append(content);
    }
}
```

Basically, if your `content` isn't a string, then put into your `$el` manually rather than going through the template.

Comment: Humm, i see, but the problem is: Underscore template does not allow me to pass a DOM node. I have to parse into HTML string before. So, as you can see the update above, i decided to replace underscore template with manual dom creation.

Comment: What's wrong with sticking with the template but dealing with different types of `content` differently?